# Angular Library How to pack the dependencies with `.tgz` file

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have created a library with new version of Angular, say 8.2.14. Now I have built the `.tgz` file by running the command `yarn package` - I am getting output as well.

After it, I am trying to install the same `tgz` file into another application, which is created by 8.1.2. But I came with errors like:

```
Error: Couldn't find package "@angular/platform-browser@~8.2.14" required by "new-lib"
```

What is the correct way here? How can I make my lib became standalone or how pack the dependencies with `package`?

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Typically stuff like `@angular/platform-browser` would be a *peer* dependency of a library, i.e. you can't use the library with a project that isn't already using Angular.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I agree with you. the issue is my angular using the plafrom-browser. but different version. Is it mandatory to use the version of what my lib uses?

Comment: You've said explicitly that your library requires ~8.2.14, which 8.1.2 **does not meet**. If your library works with other versions, use a looser spec (e.g. ^8.0.0 would cover *any* 8.x version), but we can't tell you whether that will work - you need to test your library against supported versions.